# D3 line graph - Re-render axes (x and y) when sidenav is open or close

Tags: javascript, html, angular, d3.js

I am trying to re-render the line graph when the sidenav is open or close. But the axes don't update to fit in the area when data has changed. I've tried to fix resizing when the window size is changed. My main concern is to make it behave well when the sidenav is open or close.

What else do I need to change here?

Note: It resizes correctly when the window size is changed.

```js
    const data = [
                {
                    name: 'line 1',
                    date: '2015-10-01T11:10:00.000Z',
                    value: 64
                },
                {
                    name: 'line 1',
                    date: '2015-11-01T11:15:00.000Z',
                    value: 89
                },
                {
                    name: 'line 1',
                    date: '2015-12-01T11:20:00.000Z',
                    value: 10
                },
                {
                    name: 'line 2',
                    date: '2015-10-01T11:10:00.000Z',
                    value: 64
                },
                {
                    name: 'line 2',
                    date: '2015-11-01T11:15:00.000Z',
                    value: 12
                },
                {
                    name: 'line 2',
                    date: '2015-12-01T11:20:00.000Z',
                    value: 75
                },
                {
                    name: 'line 3',
                    date: '2015-10-01T11:10:00.000Z',
                    value: 41
                },
                {
                    name: 'line 3',
                    date: '2015-11-01T11:15:00.000Z',
                    value: 80
                },
                {
                    name: 'line 3',
                    date: '2015-12-01T11:20:00.000Z',
                    value: 80
                }
            ];
    
    function createChart() {
        d3.selectAll("#chart > *").remove();

        // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
        var margin = { top: 10, right: 25, bottom: 45, left: 40 },
            width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 180 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // Parse the date / time
        var parseUTCDate = d3.utcParse('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ');
        var formatUTCDate = d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m-%d');
        var parseDate = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');
        
        // Set the ranges
        var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
        // Define the line
        var priceline = d3
            .line()
            .x(function(d) {
                return x(d['date']);
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return y(d['value']);
            });

        // Adds the svg canvas
        var svg = d3
            .select("#chart")
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .call(responsivefy)
            .append('g')
            .attr(
                'transform',
                'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')'
            );

        // Get the data
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(formatUTCDate(parseUTCDate(d.date)));
            d.value = d.value;
        });
        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(
            d3.extent(data, function(d) {
                return d.date;
            })
        );
        y.domain([
            0,
            d3.max(data, function(d) {
                return d.value;
            })
        ]);
        // Nest the entries by name
        var dataNest = d3
            .nest()
            .key(function(d) {
                return d['name'];
            })
            .entries(data);
        // set the colour scale
        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
        // Loop through each name / key
        var legendSpace = width / dataNest.length; // spacing for legend

        // Loop through each name / key
        dataNest.forEach(function(d, i) {
            svg.append('path')
                .attr('class', 'line')
                .style('stroke', function() {
                    return (d['color'] = color(d.key));
                })
                .attr('d', priceline(d.values));

            // Add the Legend
            svg.append('text')
                .attr('x', legendSpace / 2 + i * legendSpace)
                .attr('y', height + margin.bottom / 2 + 18)
                .attr('class', 'legend')
                .style('fill', function() {
                    return (d['color'] = color(d.key));
                })
                .text(d.key);
        });
        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'axis')
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

        function responsivefy(svg) {
            // get container + svg aspect ratio
            var container = d3.select(svg.node().parentNode),
                width = parseInt(svg.style('width')),
                height = parseInt(svg.style('height')),
                aspect = width / height;
            // add viewBox and preserveAspectRatio properties,
            // and call resize so that svg resizes on inital page load
            svg.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + width + ' ' + height)
                .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMid')
                .call(resize);

            // register multiple listeners for same event type,
            d3.select(window).on('resize.' + container.attr('id'), resize);

            // get width of container and resize svg to fit it
            function resize() {
                var targetWidth = parseInt(container.style('width'));
                svg.attr('width', targetWidth);
                svg.attr('height', Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
            }
        }
    }
    createChart();
```

```css
    path {
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2;
        fill: none;
    }
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .legend {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-anchor: middle;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.12.0/d3.js" integrity="sha256-3BMRAc+yX0neFRvyfGGfd3aZK8NKwYTOzq93ubNY2iU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div #chart id="chart"></div>
```